# Terminal Hangs (Not Responding)

Tags: terminal, mojave, performance

How can I fix a `Terminal` hang?

Almost every time after the `Terminal` app goes out of focus, when I move away onto a different app, and then return to it the app just hangs. Sometimes it is only for a second or two, but most of the times it lasts longer, about 30+ seconds.
I opened the `Activity Monitor` to see what is going on when I bring the `Terminal` app back into focus and here are the two types of behavior:

- The CPU usage goes up to 50-60% and the app hangs for a few seconds.
- Or the CPU goes above 70%, the app hangs for longer, and the `Activity Monitor` reports **(Not Responding)**.
  [image]

I removed the number of `Terminal` tabs opened and behavior is the same.
It seems to me it gets worse the longer the app runs. Not quite sure about this theory. I haven't had enough time to test it out.
Besides installing `iTerm` (which works fine) I haven't found a solution to this hang issue. The settings on `iTerm` are the same as `Terminal`.

I'm running *macOS Mojave 10.14.6* and *Terminal 2.9.5*.

Comment: Even if there is no command running, it can hang? And actually, app names are not so good for code format. they are very well readable in normal text.

Comment: @ankii No commands running.